# How can I program a Baofeng BF-H7 on Linux?

Tags: baofeng, linux, chirp

I recently purchased a Baofeng BF-H7, but I am unable to locate support for it on Chirp on Linux. Additionally, WINE does not support the actual software.

Are there any Chirp alternatives that I can use to program the radio, or is there a Chirp setting that I'm overlooking? Thank you.

(Yes, I have both a marine and an aviation VHF license. However, I also use the radio while hiking because I don't want to constantly carry around my marine radio.)

Answer (score 4):

According to multiple pages I found (among which [this page](https://illegalbytes.com/2021-08-17/programming-baofeng-bf-h7-with-chirp/)), the radio should be programmable with Chirp if you use the settings for the `Radioddity GA-510`.

A couple of settings cannot be changed from within Chirp (mentioned are the start screen).

I do not own the radio so cannot check for you. If you manage to try, please let us know if that works.

Regarding Chirp under Linux, [that shouldn't be an issue](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Running_Under_Linux), with flatpack, PPA and snap options available.